# Error when trying to execute grade publish command

Tags: java, gradle, repository

I'm a beginner with gradle and I created an API for mysql and jedis. Now I want to send my project to a artifact repository . I searched how to do that and I fond the solution using "gradle publish". But when I run the command I have an error and I don't realy know why :/

build.gradle:

```
java
/*
* This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
* by 'ronan' at '12/10/17 21:40' with Gradle 2.10
*/


group 'net.annorit24'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description 'API for Redis & Msyql'

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url         
"https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-        
releases"
   }
}

configurations {
   // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    extraLibs "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"
    extraLibs group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.9.0'
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it :         
zipTree(it) }
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/MIz0ZkX9Peab1z9j3ZM8/'
            credentials {
                username 'myUsername'
                password 'myPassword'
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Logs : https://pastebin.com/CqDVixy6

If someone have an idea or can help me

Yours faithfully

Comment: your link, https://hastebin.com/neqaxobupu.sql, is empty.

Comment: Oh sorry I'll update it

Comment: Does `publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal` work for you?

Comment: I did not see much issue in the attached code, maybe you can turn on the debug to give me more info.